# Theoretically, is BNF sufficient to describe all file format?

Tags: theory, bnf

Is there any kind of file format that can't be described by BNF?

Answer (score 2):

No, BNF isn't sufficient. BNF describes [context-free grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), which aren't even close to all imaginable grammars. Pretty much all programming languages, most if not all sane data serialization formats, etc. *are* context-free, but since you asked about theory, the answer is no. For starters, there are [context-sensitive grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar), which (if the name didn't tip you off) can't be expressed with context-free grammars. A simple example would be `n` times `a` followed by `n` times `b` followed by `n` times `c` (the same `n` for each).

Also, grammars only describe, well, the grammar or syntax. Depending on the file format, there may be much more required for some data in that format to be valid (well-formed) - think typechecking in programming languages, for instance. You can't describe such semantics constraints with context-free grammars, or most grammars for that matter. There may be some highly complex ones that can do it in theory. They'd be correspondingly impractical, of course.

Comment: Can it be used to describe file format like `ELF` and `PE`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. BNF only describes context free grammars. If a file contains a description of its own syntax, the rules for reading such a file couldn't be expressed in BNF. You would need a Turing machine for that. Similarly, if the decision to accept or reject a file can't be expressed by a push down automata then bnf won't work either.

BNF can't perfectly describe English syntax, for example.

Comment: Can it be used to describe file format like `ELF` and `PE`?

Comment: No. Definitely not PE (and probably not elf). Reading a PE file requires dereferencing pointers. I imagine an ELF file would too (I know for certain because I've written PE readers / writers, but I haven't looked at the ELF format in depth). That can't be expressed in BNF. You can pretty easily write hand written recursive descent to do most the reading of a PE file though.

Comment: You mentioned `You can pretty easily write hand written recursive descent to do most the reading of a PE file though.`,but how?

Comment: Take a look at the PE/Coff spec. You can download it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119. It describes the binary format of a PE file. Start by reading the headers, then the section table, etc. The code to read that looks very similar to the implementation of a parser....